# How can I prevent `[` and `]` to be parsed as array in JavaScript from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have array in my PHP like this:

```
$arr['itemDetail[0][itemDescription]'] = Sample Product;
$arr['itemDetail[0][itemPrice]'] = 50000;
$arr['itemDetail[0][itemQty]'] = 2;
$arr['itemDetail[1][itemName]'] = Sample Product Again;
$arr['itemDetail[1][itemDescription]'] = Sample Product Again;
$arr['itemDetail[1][itemPrice]'] = 150000;
$arr['itemDetail[1][itemQty]'] = 1;
```

That array will be parsed into URI with:

```
$uri = '/process?'.http_build_query($arr);
```

Then I retrieve the parameter in JavaScript with:

```
<?php foreach ($params as $_key => $_val): ?>
    <script>console.log("<?php echo $_key; ?> <?php echo $_val; ?>");</script>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Why does in my JavaScript console the value in `$_key` and `$_val` returned `itemDetail Array`?

What I expect for the `console.log();` is to return:

```
itemDetail[0][itemDescription] Sample Product
itemDetail[0][itemPrice] 50000
itemDetail[0][itemQty] 2
itemDetail[1][itemName] Sample Product Again
itemDetail[1][itemDescription] Sample Product Again
itemDetail[1][itemPrice] 150000
itemDetail[1][itemQty] 1
```

And not

```
itemDetail array
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I just realize from `itemDetail array`, `array` is actually a string. But I have just changed `$arr` into proper, multi-dimensional, PHP array and still return the same thing.

Comment: Your code works just [fine](https://www.darkbee.be/stack/php_array.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP array is read by 'echo' as word 'array'. You need to encode array to js-string by PHP and then parse it with JS:

`<?php foreach ($params as $_key => $_val): ?>
    <script>console.log("<?php echo $_key; ?> JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_val); ?>')");</script>
<?php endforeach ?>`